# How can I keep the right column of a bootstrap grid resizing without changing its position?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid

I'm building a WP theme using bootstrap. The blog page has two columns, one for the content and one for the sidebar. The problem is the right column with the sidebar moves to the position below the left one too soon when there's still enough space. By too soon I mean before the screen gets 850px size. Even though I let the bootstrap.css standard value of width:50%, this behavior will also happen. How can I keep the right column resizing without changing its position?

**Div Grid**

```
<div class="blogpage">
  <div class="col-md-6 blogpage-first-columm"><?
$myposts = get_posts(''); foreach($myposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?> <div class="post-item"> <div class="post-info"> <h2 class="post-title"> <a id="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?> </a> </h2> <p class="post-meta">Posted by <?php the_author(); ?></p> </div> <div class="post-content"> <?php the_content(); ?> </div> </div><?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?></div>
  <div class="col-md-6 blogpage-second-columm"><?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'custom-side-bar' ) ) : ?>
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'custom-side-bar' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.blogpage {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.blogpage-second-columm {
   max-width: 355px;
   padding-top: 15px;

}
.blogpage-first-columm {
   width: 70%;

}
.widget-content {
   max-width: 350px;
   margin-left: auto;
}
.widget-title-box {
   border-top-left-radius: 3px;
   border-left: 4px solid #03A8F4;
   border-top-right-radius: 3px;
   border-right: 1px solid #cccccc;
   border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
.recent-post-title {
   margin-left: 5px;
   color: #000000;
   padding-top: 5px;
}
.recent-post-title-box {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-left: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me hours to find out the answer. Instead of using col-md-6, it's better to use col-xs-6 or col-sm-6. It works perfectly when the two columns are set to be at width: 50%. I'm still testing with different percentages.

The fact is col-md will make columns wrap too early and not keep their width long enough.